# passing object between ListView and Webservices class

Tags: android

I have a class A which is responsible for fetching data from web services in android and i have a class B which is responsible for creating and rendering List View in android

Now how can i populate data on List View once the data is fetched successfully.
well i have following options but which one is better .. (if someone has anyother then i don't mind)

> 1) Create an intent of Class B and
>   pass the data that need to be
>   populated
>
> 2) Creating a static method int Class
>   B which will accept the data as an
>   argument and call setListAdapter

in class B i have used Holder Patter to create ListActivity. ( for reference List14.java in samples of Android )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 [is not a good idea, IMHO](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/08/decoupled-activities.html).

Option #2 is impossible, since `setListAdapter()` is not a static method.

Class A's responsibility should be to fetch **and store** data from Web services. Here, "store" could be:

- A database
- A flat file
- Data cached in a custom `Application` object
- Data cached in a static data member

Class A can then notify class B to get the data from the store. Here, "notify" could be:

- a broadcast `Intent`
- using the `PendingIntent` from `createPendingResult()`
- some other `PendingIntent`
- a callback or listener object registered by Class B on Class A via `bindService()` and use of the subsequent local service API (assuming class A is a `Service`)

Comment: well i am planning to store data in static data members for Class A and for class B i think last option i.e. to use call back or listener is better. as my Class B is responsible for creating ListView.

so the scenario is to fetch data by class A and newly returned data i.e. title and description want to populate on listview